# What is the easiest way to position elements within a container to any secified percentage, without a container overflow?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is there a way to position elements within a container in a similar way, as you would position background images?

CSS `image-position` works absolutely amazing:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  background-image:
    url('http://placekitten.com/100/100'),
    url('http://placekitten.com/100/100'),
    url('http://placekitten.com/100/100'),
    url('http://placekitten.com/100/100'),
    url('http://placekitten.com/100/100');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 0%, 25% 25%, 50% 50%, 75% 75%, 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Whatever percentage you set, that will be the position of your background image, with no container overflow.

However when you position elements using `left, right, top, bottom` properties, this type of positioning doesn't work the same. Trying to achieve the same result as the one above can be quite cumbersome:

```css
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: relative;
    }
    .container img {
      position: absolute;
     }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="kitten" style="left: 0%; top: 0%;">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="kitten" style="left: 25%; top: 25%; transform: translate(-25%, -25%);">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="kitten" style="left: 50%; top:50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="kitten" style="left: 75%; top: 75%; transform: translate(-75%, -75%);">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="kitten" style="left: 100%; top: 100%; transform: translate(-100%, -100%);">
</div>
```

So my question is - what would be the easiest way to position elements within a container to any specified percentage? Is there any better way than the one I showed?

Comment: What is easier or better depends on how you define those terms. This is opinion-based as currently written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS variables:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--x);
  top: var(--y);
  transform: translate(calc(-1*var(--x)), calc(-1*var(--y)));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="kitten" style="--x: 0%; --y: 0%;">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="kitten" style="--x: 25%; --y: 25%;">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="kitten" style="--x: 50%; --y:50%;">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="kitten" style="--x: 75%; --y: 75%">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="kitten" style="--x: 100%; --y: 100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: That is a great idea! Didn't think of that.
I also wonder, is there any downside or any side effect to using `transform: translate` on each element?

Comment: @IcyFoxe not really since your elements are position:absolute anyway